# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: clicked in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

js application. Need help to resolve this issue.
I have app.js which is node, calls index.html. The index.html intern calls main.js function clicked. It works fine when I have funtion 'clicked()' embeded inside index.html using script tag. But does not work if function clicked is in a seperate js file. I think this is something regarding to node.js but unable to figure out. Please find my code below.

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var request = require('request');
request('http://localhost:8000/test', function (error, response, body)     {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
console.log(body);
}
});

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
console.log('Request was made:' + req.url);
res.writeHead(200,{'content-Type': 'text/html'});
var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html','utf8');
myReadStream.pipe(res);
});
server.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1');
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
<title> Login</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<center>
    <h1> Login </h1>
</center>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="UserName"></br>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="PassWord"></br>
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="clicked()">
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
function clicked() {
var user = document.getElementById('username');
var pass = document.getElementById('password');

var checkuser = "test";
var checkpass = "123"

if (user.value == checkuser) {
    if (pass.value == checkpass) {
        window.alert("You are logged in as "+ "'"+user.value+"'");
        open("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
    else
    window.alert("Incorrect username or Password"); 
     }
    else
    window.alert("Incorrect username or Password");
  }
```

ScreenShot of the Error:

[image: ScreenShot of the Error]

Comment: It seems the Node.js server does not serve `main.js`

Comment: Where is `main.js` in relation to `index.html`? Based on the screenshot it looks like they are not in the same directory.

Comment: I realized `main.js` is already served (as it appears in the Resources panel). This is a path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Node.js server does not serve `main.js` correctly -- According to the browser's "Resources" panel, `main.js` is available, but its path is not `/main.js`.

Low level Node.js server code and Express framework code co-exist, which is not a good idea.

To solve the problem with low level Node.js code:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
  console.log('Request was made:' + req.url);

  if (req.url === '/main.js') {
    res.writeHead(200,{'content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    var jsReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/main.js','utf8');
    jsReadStream.pipe(res);
    return;
  }

  res.writeHead(200,{'content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html','utf8');
  myReadStream.pipe(res);
});
```

To solve the problem with Express framework:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
app.get('/main.js', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/main.js')); // where main.js located.
});

app.set('port', 3000);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: This is kinda overkill. OP is already pulling in Express and probably doesn't need access to low level primitives.

Comment: @SamH. The implementation is in low level because OP start the Node.js server using `http.createServer(function(req,res`... Anyway, I'll add the Express implementation. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @SamH. I've realized that main.js is already served. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `http` and `express`, which is probably unnecessary. I would serve static files with `app.use(express.static('public'))`, per [the docs.](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)  Then you can serve the index with

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
});
```

And start the server with `app.listen(3000);`

Comment: Btw make sure main.js is in a directory called public, and public and app.js should be at the same level